# Абстрактные классы С++. Пытаюсь создать СуперЮзера от Юзера. Но когда происходит сравнение стрингов, при правильном логине, он все равно повторяется

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

1. ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <clocale>


   using namespace std;

   class User { private: int password; string login;

   public: User(int password, string login) : password(password),
   login(login) {}

   User() {}

   public: virtual int getPassword() const {
       return password; }

   virtual const string &getLogin() const {
       return login; } };

   class SuperUser : public User { public: SuperUser(int i, string p) {

   } };


   int main() { setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");

   SuperUser superUser(123, "Asad");

   string login; cout << "Please, enter your login - " << endl; cin >>
   login; while (login != superUser.getLogin()) {
       cout << "Wrong! Try again" << endl;
       cin >> login; }

   return 0; }
   ```

Comment: У вас ошибка в конструкторе, и имя суперпользователя `superUser.getLogin()` - пустое.

Comment: Тут отсутствуют абстрактные классы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс SuperUser нужно переписать где то так

```
class SuperUser : public User 
{
public:
  SuperUser(int i, string p) : User(i, p) {

} };
```

В противном случае значения логина/пароля у суперюзера будет не то, которое Вы ожидаете.

Также, не забудьте у пользователя сделать вирутальный деструктор (на будущее).

Comment: Спасибо! Можно поинтересоваться почему вы написали это : User(i, p). И здесь говорят что нет абстрактных классов.

Comment: Что бы вызвать конструктор базового класса, который собственно и инициализирует все нужное.

Comment: Абстрактные классы здесь может и не нужны. Просто в вашем случае получается, что класс `SuperUser` принципиально ничем не отличается от `User`. Чтобы появилось значимое отличие вам необходимо переопределить в `SuperUser` описанные вами виртуальные функции.

Comment: да, нужно. Только не сейчас. У автора вопроса нормальный минимальный пример, который показывает его проблему. Переопределение функций не добавит ясности в проблему. Единственное, что не совсем - это тема. Вот ее можно подправить